# Sum two numbers given as arguments

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to sum two numbers given one argument?

```
function sum(a) {
// code should go here
}
sum(5)(10)
```

This should return 15

Comment: please add `code should go here`

Comment: Questions asking why code isn't working should show an attempt to reduce the code to the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem, clearly describe the actual and desired behaviour (including any error messages and indicating the corresponding lines, if applicable), describe the troubleshooting steps taken thus far (including attempts at debugging the code) and be written in a way that makes the question useful to future visitors. See [mcve] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is this

```
function sum(a) {
  return function(b) {
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
const mySum = sum(5)(10) // 15
const someSum = sum(5);

someSum(10) // 15
```

Example: https://repl.it/repls/LoneDramaticParticles

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to return another function.

```
function sum(a) {
  return (b) => {
    return a + b
  }
}
```

Not terribly extensible that way, perhaps if you added info about *why* you want to do this it'd help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called currying. You can define it as follows:

```js
    function sum(a)
    {
      return (b) => {
        return a + b;
      };
    }
    
    console.log(sum(5)(10));
```